# ajax NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Tags: javascript, c#, database, networking

After passing data from aspx to ajax to WCF as shown below, the value is being received

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: URL
    data: jString,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 0,
    async: true,
})
```

When importing from WCF by connecting to DB, it takes a lot of time and Error Code 0 occurs.

This is different for each computer, and it is difficult to determine the exact cause. Does anyone know about this?

If anyone knows how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSwvj.png)

Comment: `it is difficult to determine the exact cause` .... could it be that `it takes a lot of time`? does it ever work? or does it always fail?

Comment: @Bravo Due to the large amount of data, it is taking a long time.
Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails.
I think it might be because of the node.js default time of 4 minutes.

Comment: nodejs? but you're using WCF and C# - what's nodejs involvement  - positive thing is, if you ARE using nodejs in some capacity, you can fix the issue without the brain numbing gymnastics needed to configure simple things that is IIS

Comment: @Bravo sorry. I checked and it doesn't seem to be nodejs. It's set to IIS only. help....

Comment: well, if the *server* is causing the issue, then fix the server